# Resharper spaces around negative sign

Tags: c#, resharper

We have our resharper settings set to have spaces around additive operations so

`var num = 1+2` will turn into `var num = 1 + 2`

However, we have the issue that defining a number as negative puts an unnecessary space after the negative sign, treating it as if its a minus sign.

`var num = -1` becomes `var num = - 1`

Is there a setting that will keep the behavior of the first example but avoid that of the 2nd?

My settings: http://pastebin.com/1sRjw0ZS

Comment: The option named `Additive operators` in R# options => C# => Formatting Style => Spaces should only affect the way your first example is formatted. I have that option on, and I can't repro the `- 1` behavior. So you probably have something else turned on, but I can't find any option related to that.

Comment: Maybe you could post your ReSharper team shared options so we can see what else you've set? Or try resetting your ReSharper options to the defaults?

Comment: Posted the team shared settings